# ControllerAdvice not handling exception thrown by AfterThrowing aspect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

this problem consists of 3 layes

1. Service that makes HTTP calls
2. Aspect that advices the service above when an exception is thrown
3. Spring boot's @ControllerAdvice that sets the status code before returning result to client

What I want to achieve:

1. When the Service makes an HTTP call that returns 404, I want to handle that with my aspect
2. My aspect should see that the service received 404 and then throw a custom NotFoundException
3. The ControllerAdvice should then handle this custom exception by returning 404 status code to the user.

What is happening instead is that the `ControllerAdvice` is being skipped when the Aspect is throwing the new NotFound exception, and the client is receiving `500` instead of `404`.

The code looks something like:

### Service

```
@CatchHttpResult
public Map<String, Object> getUserInfo(String email) {
    cpLocation.entering("getUserInfo");
    String url = contactUrl+"/api/getContactInfo?id="+email;
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
            Map.class);
    return respEntity.getBody();
}
```

### Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CatchHttpResultAspect {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "@annotation(CatchHttpResult)", throwing = "e")
    public void httpAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) throws Throwable {
        if (e instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
            if (((HttpClientErrorException) e).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("The requested entity was not found.");
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

### ControllerAdvice

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsController {
    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
    }
}
```

I want the ControllerAdvice to be able to handle the EntityNotFoundException, instead that code isn't reached at all.

Why is this happening and how do I get the desired behavior?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at po.repository.service.MicroserviceIntercomm$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d580a067.getUserInfo(<generated>)
    at po.repository.service.POService.getUserInfo(POService.java:523)
    at po.repository.controller.RepositoryController.initiateData(RepositoryController.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: if you get a 500, what's the stacktrace on the client side (try running with debug)

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Added. The service is basically making an HTTP request, and I want the result of the request, in case 404, to be passed to @`ControllerAdvice`, instead it's bypassing it.

Comment: Is `EntityNotFoundException` a checked exception?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll It is a checked exception.

Comment: Well then that's why. That method can't throw a checked exception so it's wrapped in `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll How do I get the expected behavior in this case then? Thank you for the help!

Comment: wrap that in a runtime and throws a runtime. And change your control advice to work on that. If the method signature doesn't throw a checked exception there's not much we can do about it.